# SQL - Select Top 1 multiple lines of the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select * from [lead].[ContactFeedback] cf
where cf.LeadId in
(select LeadId from [lead].[LeadDetails]
where TeleportReference in (122096, 
122097, 
122098))
order by LeadId Desc
```

The results are something like this :

```
FeedbackDate            LeadId         
2015-01-23 16:25:13.547 95920
2015-01-23 16:25:38.960 95919
2015-01-23 16:25:19.393 95917
2015-01-23 16:25:32.837 95916
2015-01-23 16:25:59.840 95914
2015-01-23 16:26:08.840 95913
2015-01-23 16:15:01.933 95910
2015-01-23 16:22:04.820 95910
2015-01-23 16:24:40.477 95909
2015-01-23 16:24:03.523 95908
2015-01-23 16:16:44.290 95908
2015-01-23 16:17:16.047 95907
2015-01-23 16:25:11.783 95907
```

I want to list all top 1(most recent feedbackdate) for each LeadId. How can I achieve this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select LeadId, Max(FeedbackDate) 
from [lead].[ContactFeedback] cf
where cf.LeadId in
    (select LeadId from [lead].[LeadDetails]
     where TeleportReference in (122096, 122097, 122098))
group by LeadId
order by LeadId Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window Function`

```
select leadid,feedbackdate from ( 
select row_number() over(partition by leadid order by feedbackdate desc) rn,* 
from yourtable) a
where rn=1
```

Comment: @Tim I guess he meant ranking function.

Comment: @Tim - over clause in sql server is called window function

Comment: @NoDisplayName - Never heard that before.   Downvote wasn't from me - I was just curious as to what you meant by Window function is all.

Comment: Possibly because your query is missing the filter / order by?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sub query to get the max FeedBackDate for each LeadId. Then join the detail table to that.

```
select cf.* 
from [lead].[ContactFeedback] cf
join (select LeadId, max(FeedBackDate) maxFeedBackDate
     from [lead].[ContactFeedback]
     group by LeadId) as maxes
on cf.LeadId = maxes.LeadId
   and cf.FeedBackDate = maxes.maxFeedBackDate
where cf.LeadId in
      (select LeadId 
       from [lead].[LeadDetails]
       where TeleportReference in (122096, 
                                   122097, 
                                   122098)
       )
order by cf.LeadId Desc
```

Comment: outer select is necessary only if ContactFeedback contains columns, except LeadId and FeedBackDate; otherwise it will reduce performance

Comment: @ASh You are right, not normal to just want a list of IDs and dates so was showing how you would use this to get data from a "detail table". He would have to replace the FROM table with the table he wanted to pull the data from.